# Multiple Checkbox Values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, t-sql, sqldatasource

I am amending someone else's code, and am running into a problem I can't seem to solve.  In the database, we have store locations, and five types of products sold.  If a location sells a product, the database value is "X".  If it does not, the database value is null.  The application I'm amending has a search box, with a city, zip, and now checkboxes for the five products (this is the portion just added.)  Ideally, you could only enter one parameter, and it would display the results according to what you entered/checked, or you could enter/check multiple parameters.  The city/zip bit works fine, but the results are only displaying locations that sell all 5 products - it isn't recognizing the null value.  Here's my submit function for the search form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".form #searchBtn").click(function() {
            var searchParameters = "";
            if ($(".form #city").val() != "") {
                if (searchParameters != "") {
                    searchParameters += "&";
                }
                searchParameters += "city=" + $(".form #city").val();
            }
            if ($(".form #zip").val() != "") {
                if (searchParameters != "") {
                    searchParameters += "&";
                }
                searchParameters += "zip=" + $(".form #zip").val();
            }

            if ($(".form #product1").is(':checked')) {
                        if (searchParameters != "") {
                            searchParameters += "&";
                        }
                        searchParameters += "product1=" + "X";
            }
            if ($(".form #product2").is(':checked')) {
                        if (searchParameters != "") {
                            searchParameters += "&";
                        }
                        searchParameters += "product2=" + "X";
            }
            if ($(".form #product3").is(':checked')) {
                                if (searchParameters != "") {
                                    searchParameters += "&";
                                }
                                searchParameters += "product3=" + "X";
            }
            if ($(".form #product4").is(':checked')) {
                                if (searchParameters != "") {
                                    searchParameters += "&";
                                }
                                searchParameters += "product4=" + "X";
            }
            if ($(".form #product5").is(':checked')) {
                                if (searchParameters != "") {
                                    searchParameters += "&";
                                }
                                searchParameters += "product5=" + "X";
            }
    searchParameters = searchParameters.replace(" ","%20");
            $.fn.colorbox({ href: 'locations.aspx?' + searchParameters });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code is generating a URL with the search parameters, locations.aspx?city=blah&otherParamsHere.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

***EDIT***

To answer your question, the code is all in the front end.  Here's what the query looks like for locations.aspx where it generates results.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="locations" runat="server" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [locations] WHERE (([city] LIKE '%' + @city + '%') AND ([zip] LIKE '%' + @zip + '%') AND ([product1] LIKE '%' + @product1 + '%')  AND ([product2] LIKE '%' + @product2 + '%')  AND ([product3] LIKE '%' + @product3 + '%')  AND ([product4] LIKE '%' + @product4 + '%')  AND ([product5] LIKE '%' + @product5 + '%')) ORDER BY [retailer_name]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="city" 
                QueryStringField="city" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="zip" 
                QueryStringField="zip" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="product1" 
                QueryStringField="product1" Type="String" />  
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="product2" 
                QueryStringField="product2" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="product3" 
                QueryStringField="product3" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="product4" 
                QueryStringField="product4" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="product5" 
                QueryStringField="product5" Type="String" />    
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

***EDIT***

Amending again to include form.

```
                <input type="text" id="city" size="20" />
                <input type="text" id="zip" maxlength="5" size="5" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="product1" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="product2" value="" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="product3" value="" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="product4" value="" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="product5" value="" />
                <input type="button" value="Search" id="searchBtn"/>
```

Comment: May be the problem is in your backend code in locations.aspx.cs. Could you append some part of your code behind that contains the search method?

Comment: See above...let me know if there is something else I can tell you.

Comment: See my proposal for a new Sql statement below.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR between your products in your select statements where clause, and I think you can skip some parentheses. You will only need parentheses around your OR:s, not around AND:s try this

```
SELECT * FROM [locations] 
WHERE [city] LIKE '%' + @city + '%' AND 
      [zip] LIKE '%' + @zip + '%' AND 
      ( [product1] LIKE '%' + @product1 + '%' OR 
        [product2] LIKE '%' + @product2 + '%' OR
        [product3] LIKE '%' + @product3 + '%' OR 
        [product4] LIKE '%' + @product4 + '%' OR 
        [product5] LIKE '%' + @product5 + '%'
      ) 
ORDER BY [retailer_name]
```

Comment: It's better, but still not working.  What it's doing now is respecting whatever you enter for city or zip, and returning anything that matches those, but not respecting whether or not the product boxes are checked.  If you check one, and do not enter a city or zip, it returns the entire DB.

Comment: Do you have to use LIKE comparison? Try to change it to = (equal comparison) instead.

Comment: And to clarify, if you enter a zip code and check a product, it's returning all locations within that zip, regardless of whether that product is sold or not.  It's like it's ignoring the products altogether.

Comment: Using = instead of LIKE makes every query return no results.

Comment: Ok, try please try my last attempt to correct the where clause. I think you should be able to avoid LIKE comparison and use = (equal) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the equal comparison a try also. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [locations] 
WHERE ([city] = @city OR @city = '%') AND 
      ([zip] = @zip OR @zip = '%') AND 
      ( 
          [product1] = @product1 OR @product1 = '%' OR 
          [product2] = @product2 OR @product2 = '%' OR
          [product3] = @product3 OR @product3 = '%' OR 
          [product4] = @product4 OR @product4 = '%' OR 
          [product5] = @product5 OR @product5 = '%'  
      ) 
ORDER BY [retailer_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were super close!  Because of you, I was able to poke at it until I got it correct.  Here's what my final SQL statement ended up being, and it performs the way I intended:

```
SELECT * FROM [locations] 
        WHERE ([city] = @city OR @city = '%') 
        AND ([zip] = @zip OR @zip = '%') 
        AND 
        (
        ([product1] = @product1 OR @product1 = '%') 
        AND ([product2] = @product2 OR @product2 = '%')  
        AND ([product3] = @product3 OR @product3 = '%')  
        AND ([product4] = @product4 OR @product4 = '%')  
        AND ([product5] = @product5 OR @product5 = '%'
        )) 
        ORDER BY [retailer_name]
```